# Keep the Command Line as Powershell and not CMD

Tags: windows, openssh, powershell-core

When I try and SSH from a Windows 10 box in Powershell 7 to Windows 2019 which also has Powershell 7 installed using code like this it always connects switches to a DOS shell: How can I use this command and make it stay with Powershell?

```
ssh someuser@189.0.5.7 -i ~/.ssh/key
```

Comment: Can't you just run ```pwsh``` once you're "on" the box?

Comment: That worked nicely. Thank you.